# how to call view void inside switch function

Tags: android

I'm getting a error on calling  public void `onStartTransaction(View view)` in switch function. I have tried to remove view but the function is not giving any response for this

```
public void onStartTransaction (View view){

    String orderId = pref.getoId();
    String uid = pref.getuid();
    String email = pref.getemail();
    String mobile = pref.getMobileNumber();
    String checksum = pref.getchecksum();
    PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getProductionService();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    paramMap.put("MID", "GoaInd04363263038161");
    paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", orderId);
    paramMap.put("CUST_ID", uid);
    paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail109");
    paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
    paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "99");
    paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "GoaIndWEB");
    paramMap.put("CALLBACK_URL", "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp");
    paramMap.put("EMAIL", email);
    paramMap.put("MOBILE_NO", mobile);
    paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH", checksum);
    PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);

    Service.initialize(Order, null);

    Service.startPaymentTransaction(this, true, true,
            new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {

                @Override
                public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // Some UI Error Occurred in Payment Gateway Activity.
                    // // This may be due to initialization of views in
                    // Payment Gateway Activity or may be due to //
                    // initialization of webview. // Error Message details
                    // the error occurred.
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction : " + inResponse);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Payment Transaction response " + inResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void networkNotAvailable() {
                    // If network is not
                    // available, then this
                    // method gets called.
                }

                @Override
                public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {
                    // This method gets called if client authentication
                    // failed. // Failure may be due to following reasons //
                    // 1. Server error or downtime. // 2. Server unable to
                    // generate checksum or checksum response is not in
                    // proper format. // 3. Server failed to authenticate
                    // that client. That is value of payt_STATUS is 2. //
                    // Error Message describes the reason for failure.
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode,
                                                  String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {

                }

                // had to be added: NOTE
                @Override
                public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionCancel(String inErrorMessage, Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction Failed " + inErrorMessage);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Payment Transaction Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
}


public void addListenerOnButton(){

    radioGroup= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
    pbutton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.paybutton);
    pbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);  

            int id = radioButton.getId();

            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.rb:

                    onStartTransaction();

                    break;
```

This error closes my activity. how to call this void on switch function or what is the alternative to call this type of void?

I'm getting below error

```
Error:(260, 25) error: method onStartTransaction in class selectgateway cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: If you don't share the error we can't help you : ) No magicians here as far as I know.

Comment: error is Error:(260, 25) error: method onStartTransaction in class selectgateway cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function as you've shown needs an argument of View class.

`onStartTransaction (View view)`

So to call this function or method, you need to provide an object of View class. You must call this as

`onStartTransaction(v)`

Where `v` is an object of View class.
Since you've called `onStartTransaction()` (missing argument), you're getting the error.

You can also remove the `View view` argument part from the `onStartTransaction(View view){...}` function to make it `onStartTransaction(){...}`